# PostGIS: How to find routes near to some point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

So, I have groups of polylines returned from google map API (Green, Red and Yellow), some starting point `p` (blue one), and a radius `r`. I need to find all routes whose distance from p is no greater than r (in this case red and yellow)
[image]

I know that I can calculate it manually (find equation of each line and compare it to the equation of the circle) but it can be inefficient for many routes. So my question is:

Is there builtin function in PostGIS which will help me accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better (much faster) solution is to use

> ST_Dwithin(pointgeom, linegeom, maxdistance)

Also see [manual](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

The ST_Distance function will calculate the exact distance whereas ST_DWithin stops when it knows it is in range, making it easier and faster to calculate.

Bonus: be careful to use the correct projection here, since lat-lon calculations will be in degrees, not meters.

Comment: I am not sure if it works for me. Following query should return true, but returns false. https://pastebin.com/yV8fxWKC

Comment: The distance between these two geometries is more than 2000 meters. So the answer 'false' is corrrect. Why do you think it should return true?

Comment: Because, according to google maps, from this point to nearest edge of the polyline is about 200 meters.

Comment: You must have missed a decimator somewhere, because I just double checked it, and google tells me more than 2 km. How did you measure in google maps?

Comment: It seems that I made a mistake previously, because now I double checked it and it is correct. Thanks man!